# Intellij WebStorm showing useless usage search on encapsulated React components (using HOC)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, react-redux, ide

It is basically [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41501).

While using code like

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {

}

export default withRouter(SomeComponent);
```

I can't use search usages properly, because it obviously finds the export line.

It can be hacked in functional components like this:

```
const SomeComponent = withRouter((props) => {
   //...component here
});
export default SomeComponent;
```

but gets very ugly when using redux for example:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    ....
});

const SomeComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)({
    cartPhotos,
    digitals,
    balancePrice,
    photolabPrice,
    digitalsPrice,
    voucher,
    photosPrice,
    deliveryPrice,
    totalPrice,
    openPhotolabModal,
    isSidebar,
}) => {

});
export default SomeComponent;
```

My questions are:

- Is there a way to overcome this without using such ugly approach?
- Is there a way to overcome this on a class component AT ALL?

Comment: I can't offer any workarounds for it, sorry. Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41501 for updates

Comment: Thanks @lena for trying, but you literally copied the link I already posted in my question. Anyway I think it should have a higher priority as it's kinda annoying and pretty long ongoing now. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normal that you find only one ref for SomeComponent.

SomeComponent !==  your default export

If you press right click on default and search there usages you find all that use it in import.

[image]

Comment: Also I agree that it's probably not a bug but a very often seen edge case which should have been adressed somehow if it wasn't already with this trick :-)